# DescrpitorExtractor::create("SIFT") returns 0?

Tags: c++, opencv

The following piece of code outputs 0.

```
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
cout << descriptor << endl;
```

whilethis piece of code outputs a non-zero pointer.

```
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");
cout << descriptor << endl;
```

What should I do to fix the create sift function? I have tested it with opencv 2.4.7 and 2.4.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIFT and SURF are patented, nonfree.

so, to use those, you have to

- include the "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp" header,
- link to the opencv_nonfree.lib and
- call `cv::initModule_nonfree();`
  in main() before doing anything else.

Comment: Awesome. It solved my problem. I had everything but cv::initModule_nonfree. Is this recently added? Because the same code was working before..

Comment: api keeps changing. no idea, when exactly this came in